# Trying to filter the contents of a ChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, field, choicefield

(My english no is good, sorry) I have a problem creating a form of search by location: I have the form.py currently as follows:

```
from models import City, Zone

class SearchForm1(forms.Form):
   cityf = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), empty_label="none")
   zonef = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zone.objects.all(), empty_label="none")
```

But this is displayed with all cities and areas exist in the db, and I'm trying to make is that in the 1 st field is show all cities and in the 2nd field to display only those areas corresponding to the selected city.

I tried to do so:

```
class SearchForm1(forms.Form):
   cityf = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(), empty_label="none")
   zonef = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.get(
             name_city="cityf").zone_set.all(), empty_label="none")
```

^ But I recive this ##ERROR: ^

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:

City matching query does not exist.

Exception Location:
```

I've also been looking at this: http://www.stereoplex.com/blog/filtering-dropdown-lists-in-the-django-admin But in the end it does not need to leave it someone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Since at the time the form gets rendered, the city (the first field) is not selected yet.

You could either do it in a two-step wizard-style form. Where the first form only has the city, then the second form only the zone. In the second form you filter the zones using the city that was selected in the first form.

Alternatively you could to it using javascript where you filter the second field depending on the first field.

Comment: Thank you very much, try creating 2 forms, but you could give me an example of how could do this using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the feature Grouped Selects in [django smart selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). Check out this answer to a duplicate question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390892/538471