# In Django Admin, can options depend on some other value?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have 3 models in Django: Country, City, and Store.
When I create a new store in Django admin, I want to choose Country and City.
After I decide the Country, how can I make the options in City relate to the Country?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects). Also described [here in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields/8390892#8390892).

Comment: This library doesn't support Django > 4.0.

Comment: 10 years. Times fly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)