# Django admin: how to limit related selectbox values based on another selectbox

Tags: django, django-admin

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    leve1 = models.ForeignKey( Level1 )
    leve2 = models.ForeignKey( Level2 )
    leve3 = models.ForeignKey( Level3 )
    leve4 = models.ForeignKey( Level4 )



class Level1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Level2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leve1 = models.ForeignKey( Level1 )

class Level3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leve2 = models.ForeignKey( Level2 )

class Level4(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leve3 = models.ForeignKey( Level3 )
```

in Django Admin refining selectbox values based on another selectbox

use formfield_for_foreignkey? raw_id_fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [customizing admin of django to have dependent select fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Django Smart Selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)