# dynamic dropdown list in python GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dynamic, drop-down-menu, django-templates

I am using GAE with Python for building an app. I have 2 dropdowns 'applications' and 'versions' in my firstpage( Index.html). I am able to populate the first dropdown dynamically from the database. Based on the selection of the first dropdown, I need to populate the second. I tried with an onchange event and a javascript to capture the selection id in the first dropdown list. but i am not sure how to pass the captured onchangeid to the backend. request.get doesn't seem to work. Appreciate any help.

my main.py looks like

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
      proj = db.GqlQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Applicationname FROM Dashboard")

      Appname1 = self.request.get('selvalue.value')
      proj1 = Dashboard.all().filter('Applicationname =',Appname1)

      values = {'appnames' : proj, 'vernums' : proj1}
      self.response.out.write(template.render('index.html',values))

class Dashboard(db.Model):
   Applicationname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
   Version=db.StringProperty(required=True)
   Type=db.StringProperty()
   Pagename=db.StringProperty(required=True)
   Responsetime=db.StringProperty(required=True)


class DisplayHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
      Appname=self.request.get('Applicationname')
      Vernum=self.request.get('Version')
      query = Dashboard.all().filter('Applicationname =',Appname).filter('Version =',Vernum)
      values = {'query' : query}
      self.response.out.write(template.render('response.html',values))

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                     [('/', MainPage),
                                      ('/Display', DisplayHandler)
                                     ],
                                     debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

my index.html looks like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My First Web Page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </link>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(Applicationname)
{
var selvalue = document.getElementById("Applicationname");      
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/Display" method="post">

        <select name="Applicationname" id="Applicationname" onchange="myFunction()"  >
            <option value="Select">---Select---</option>
                {% for q in appnames %}
            <option value="{{q.Applicationname}}">{{q.Applicationname}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
</select>

 <br><br>

Select the Version number
        <select name="Version" id="Version">
            <option value="Select">---Select---</option>
            {% for r in vernums %}
            <option value="{{q.Version}}">{{r.Version}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [customizing admin of django to have dependent select fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields)

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainPage.get()` routine looks like it's expecting a query string `selvalue.value`.  Change your `index.html` like this:

```
<select name="Applicationname" id="Applicationname"
 onchange="document.location.href='/?selvalue.value="+this.value+"'"  >
```

This will cause the page to reload and show the `vernums` for the specified `Applicationname`.

This is not the only way to solve this problem, but it is the shortest.

Comment: Thanks Brent. I tried the above but still I am not able to retrieve the selected value in my main.py. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: What didn't work, specifically?  Maybe you need to URI-encode the value? `onchange="document.location.href='/?selvalue.value="+encodeURIComponent(this.value)+"'"`

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at `django-smart-select` or this question: [customizing admin of django to have dependent select fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields)

Answer (score 0):

I built something to do this a while ago.  Read the bottom of this page for an explanation of what you'd need to do to build this:

https://github.com/dragonx/django-hier-ajax-form/blob/master/README.rst

I found out later that there's an existing project that does the same thing:

https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects