# django model field depend on the value of another field

Tags: python, django, django-models

The use case of my application is I will have various fields to fill and among them one is Industry field and another is Segment Field for brand. The industry field is like category that brand falls into. So, if i choose the `industry` as `Health Care` for `XYZ brand` then the `segment` field should show the items like 'Ayurveda', 'Dental Clinics' (all health care related items). Basically, its like sub-category.

Here is a sample model

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Industry'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Industries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Segment(models.Model):
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, related_name='segment', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Segment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Segments'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.industry.name} - {self.name}'


class BusinessModel(models):
    industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry, blank=False, null=False, related_name='industry', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # segements = models.ForeignKey()
    total_investment = models.CharField() # will be choice field
```

This is a simple model and I have not created Segment model as I am not sure how to approach to this problem. I am just curios to know, if for such case, do i have to something special in `models.py` or in the view side. Such type of things get arise during development phase, thus, I want to be clear on problem solving pattern in django.

UPDATE

https://www.franchisebazar.com/franchisor-registration here if you choose industry inside Business model section, the segment will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a 3 model design like

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

class Mapping(models.Model):
     industry = models.ForeignKey(Industry)
     segment = models.ForeignKey(Segment)
```

Comment: so mapping should be a foreign key in BusinessModel table instead of separate Industry and Segment table?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Mapping is an associative entity relating Industy and Segment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: I will look into it, thanks. Meanwhile, is that associative entity is like through in manytomany ?

Comment: yes, many to many will make an associative entity under the hood. If you need to track information about the relationship itself you'll want to add it as it's own model. Depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define relations between your models. You can find documentation about ManyToMany relation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) which is suitable in your case.

Comment: Business model should fall only under one industry and industry has multiple segments but the segment inside business model will have only one. I mean if i have choose health care then it has multiple segments but from those multiple segments, i can choose only one value.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ChainedForeginKey.. Check the below links

[customizing admin of django to have dependent select fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-field)

https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Comment: This answer looks like a [Link Only Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). When answering a question, you absolutely can link to external resources, but at least explain how and why it is relevant to this case, maybe giving a little bit of context, etc...