# How can i filter a manytomany field based on a foreign key?(I the django Admin panel itself)

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield

I have a `many-to-many` relation on field `tag` and a foreign key field `appName`, I want to select only the tags that are related to the specific appNames.

Now, when the dropdown for selection is opened it displays all the many-to-many fields irrespective of its related apps.

```
    class AppName(models.Model):

        appId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        appName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        appVersion = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
        appVersionName = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
        appPackageName = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Tag(models.Model):

        tagId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        tag = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        tagDes = models.TextField()
        tagAddedDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        appName = models.ForeignKey(AppName,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class Company(models.Model):

        CId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        appName =  models.ForeignKey(AppName,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True)
```

The expected output is a list of tags with respect to the appName selected.

Comment: Don't you just `filter` by appName?

Comment: `Tag.objects.filter(appName=myAppName)`.

Comment: i mean i wanna filter the tags based on appName in the models itself .like when adding the data into the database thrugh the admin panel then after i select a app name from it then i should only be able to select the tags related to that only.is that possible?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields) post.

Comment: Thank you.But that didnt work.I am looking to change the list in the django admin page

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear for me, but it seems that you want to have 'chained' dropdown lists. As far as i know it is not doeable without some requests.

I followed tutorial from:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

and it worked perfectly in my case. So basically you need some ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks ..but i am not working with forms here ..instead i wanna do this chained dropdown b/w a foregine key filed and m2m filed in the django admin page itself

Comment: Then by all means - write in the question - that you mean the django-admin-page.