# Related drop-down lists in the Django admin panel?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

how do I make linked drop-down lists in the Django admin panel?
there are 3 models
when you add a category to products, for example, electronics, and only what is related to electronics fell out in the subcategory.

```
class Products(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название')
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Категория')
subcategory = models.ForeignKey('SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='subКатегория')

class Category(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')

class SubCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')
category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380241/customizing-admin-of-django-to-have-dependent-select-fields